# Create a macro with a file path that has a date variable

Tags: vba, date, filepath, userform

I would like to open an Excel file which has a date variable at the end. To date I have created an okay code to retrieve the file based on working backwards from the current date. I would prefer a userform or input box to specify the exact date needed. The date is in the `ddmmyyyy` format and is at the end of the filename. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Sub OpenLatest()
  ---Opens a sheet based on date, searches backward from today til it finds   a  matching date
Dim TestDate As Date
Dim StartWB As String

Const sPath As String = "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\"
Const dtEarliest = #6/1/2015#  '--to stop loop if file not found by earliest valid date.

TestDate = Date
StartWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

While ActiveWorkbook.Name = StartWB And TestDate >= dtEarliest
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open sPath & "Firstmacro_dtetime1 " & Format(TestDate, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"
    TestDate = dtTestDate - 1
    On Error GoTo 0
Wend

If ActiveWorkbook.Name = sStartWB Then MsgBox "Earlier file not found."
End Sub'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `InputBox()` function to request a date from the user.

```
Dim strDate As String
strDate = InputBox("Enter a date:")

If Not IsDate(strDate) Then
    MsgBox "Not a date"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Create the file path...
Dim strPath As String
strPath = "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\Firstmacro_dtetime1 " & Format$(strDate, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"

' Make sure it exists...
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If .FileExists(strPath) Then
        Workbooks.Open strPath
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your assitance on this. Unfortunately the macro is not working for me. It's failing recognise the date that I'm inputing in the inputbox. The file path exists as I've checked this in the immediate window, so I tried another bit of code but now have a new problem. Its failing to recognise the date format I am entering.

Comment: 'Sub OpenLatest()
Dim strDate As Date
strDate = Format(strDate, "ddmmyyyy")
strDate = InputBox("Enter a date:")

If Not IsDate(strDate) Then
    MsgBox "Not a date"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Create the file path...

Dim strPath As String
strPath = C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\Firstmacro_dtetime1 " & Format(strDate, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"

' Make sure it exists...
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If .FileExists(strPath) Then
        Workbooks.Open strPath
    End If
End With
End Sub'

Comment: You can't use `Format()` beforehand to specify how the date should be entered. The user will have to enter the date in a traditional format (`1/2/15`,  `1-2-15`, `2015/1/2`, etc.). Otherwise, it will just be treated as a string. But if you need to do it that way, we can parse the string to create a date from it.

Comment: Thank you very much Bond. I will try and parse the date with a String.